# Using fs read file I want to the json data in variable to pass to the nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, path, fs

I am trying to use fs.readFile in my nodejs project. I want to read the file from a different location in the computer system and read it. After reading I want to store that JSON data into the object and access it into my project. Can anyone please help me with this I am stuck with a problem for a long time.

```
fs = require('fs');
path = require('path');
const location = path.join('/users/', 'hello.json');
let rawdata = fs.readFile(location, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data){
let Issuedata = data;
});
```

Comment: You'll have to show us what you're actually trying to do with the data you read.  If you're going to use `fs.readFile()`, then you should use the data inside the callback you passed to it or call some other function from there and pass the data to that function.  Otherwise, if this is just server initialization code, you can use `fs.readFileSync()` which will synchronously return the data.

Comment: Can you show me an example of it?

Comment: Example of what?  `fs.readFileSync()` is fully described in the doc.  As I already said, we could offer more help if you showed what you're really trying to do with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this

```
const {readFile} = require('fs/promises'); // using fs-promises
const path = require('path');
const file = path.join("/users/", "hello.json");
const dataObj = {}; // object you intend to use

readFile(file, {encoding: 'utf-8'}).then((result) => {

if(!dataObj[result]) {
  dataObj[result] = JSON.parse(result);
  }
});

console.log(dataObj) // result
```

The JSON file is read first, the result gotten from the `readFile` function is appended to the `dataObj` object. Hope it can help you or steer you in the right direction